# What are some of the reasons for which mainstream non-Catholic Christians are against gender-neutral secular marriage?

Tags: same-sex-marriage, civil-government

What are some of the reasons for which [mainstream](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity) non-Catholic Christians are against gender-neutral secular marriage?

I get that some churches won't acknowledge **religious** gender-neutral or same-sex marriage (GNM) and why they won't support GNM,

but why exactly does that extend to being outright **against** (as opposed to having no stand) **secular** GNM?

Besides homophobia (like with the Westboro Baptist Church and the sort) and possibly the arguments [here](http://tech.mit.edu/V124/N5/kolasinski.5c.html), what are there?

In case the article is too long for you, [here](http://squashed.tumblr.com/post/426856180/there-is-no-secular-case-against-gay-marriage) is a response that takes the article apart.

I guess [mainstream](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/888/22013) is:

Orthodox (e.g. Eastern Orthodox, Greek Orthodox, Russian Orthodox, etc...)

Roman Catholic

Protestant (Lutheran, Baptist, Methodist, Episcopalian, etc...)

Historic Non-Chalcedonian Churches (Coptic, Armenian, Ethiopian, Nestorian, etc..)

Jehovah's Witness

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints (Mormons)

Seventh-Day Adventists

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "besides homophobia"? People mean all sorts of different things by that word.

Comment: You might find this site interesting: http://mormonsandgays.org/

Comment: The organizations and people you encompass when you use the term "non-catholic Christians" is still way too broad for the site in my opinion. For example, there are Lutherans who have no objection to marriage between two individuals of the same sex, while other Lutherans are categorically and completely opposed. Same is true with Anglicans, Methodists, and Presbyterians. This question almost has to be asked with respect to each denominational organization.

Comment: @DJClayworth The Westboro Baptist Church is against secular GNM partly due to hating gay people, afaik. So what are some arguments that aren't due to hate? I mean, technically WBC is Christian despite it being practically un-Christian due to it being a hate group right?

Comment: @brasshat Is this question significantly different from a question like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092945/asking-for-various-proofs-of-uncountability-of-0-1 because there are really TOO MANY arguments? I am thinking that their arguments will be similar. For instance, Methodists and Anglicans may have different bases for a particular argument which will be the same. Would it help if I revised the question to official positions of mainstream churches?

Comment: @BCLC, yes a question, or series of questions, about the positions of individual mainstream church bodies would be much more in scope of the site.

Comment: @brasshat Is your yes to my first question (too many arguments), my second question (revised *the* question to official positions of mainstream churches) or both?

Comment: @BCLC, "Yes" is a response to the question _Would it help if I revised the question to official positions of mainstream churches?"_ in your comment.

Comment: @brasshat Oh sorry. I think I missed 'a question, or' in your answer. Hehe

Comment: @BCLC You seem to be trying to conduct an argument in the comments section. Please don't do that. In fact please don't use this site to have an argument at all. If you have more specific questions, please ask them as a separate question.

Comment: @DJClayworth In what am I trying to conduct an argument? I do not understand what ShemSeger is trying to say so I am asking.

Comment: @brasshat Edited to mainstream

Comment: @BCLC Because every time someone gives you an answer you try to invalidate that answer. Because you ask accusatory 'follow-up' questions. Because you ask for clarifications on things that you claimed originally to know the answer to. Because you say things like "Okay, so you presented the assumptions. What is the argument?". Because you feel the need to reply to every single comment that is made, and every answer that is presented. Because you keep talking about answers that don't "make an argument".

Comment: @BCLC: DJClayworth is right. Don't carry on arguments *or* discussions in comments. I've deleted said comments.

Comment: @BCLC, even editing it to specifically define a list of different groups you identify as "mainstream" leaves the question to broad, in my opinion. To be narrow enough to be within scope, each of the groups you cite (except "Roman Catholics", who are excluded by the fact that they are not "non-catholic") should be the topic of a single question, and perhaps sometimes broken down further. "Lutherans" as a class, for example, would be too broad, because among those who self-identify as Lutheran, some accept **religious** GNM, while others reject **secular** GNM.

Answer (score 1):

Christians believe that God's law is not an arbitrary set of rules designed to make life inconvenient, but that it represents God's intended pattern for living a happy, successful, fulfilled life.

Many Christians believe that following God's pattern for human behaviour therefore results in more fulfilled people and a better society, whether or not those people believe in the source of the pattern (God). Many also believe that it is the duty of secular authorities to  promote moral behaviour; and especially the duty of Christians to use whatever influence they have on the government to make it promote moral behaviour.

Comment: This seems not really like an argument/s but more like an assumption/s of the argument/s. What exactly does this have to do with secular GNM? I am not asking why Christians are giving their opinions based on their beliefs to the state. I think it's great that people can and do speak up for what they believe. My question is why do some Christians think their beliefs on religious GNM apply to secular GNM or if not, why are they against secular GNM (I think it is possible to be against religious GNM and against secular GNM for diff reasons)? What exactly is the immoral behaviour in secular GNM?

Comment: @BCLC You posted this already, but it doesn't make sense. You said you understood why some Christians were against homosexual practice. So why are you now asking "What exactly is the immoral behaviour in secular same-sex marriage?". Isn't it obvious? If you really don't know the answer, then please ask a new question.

Comment: I don't understand how your post answers my question. So some Christians are against homosexual sex and religious GNM. What exactly do either or both have to do with some of those Christians being additionally against secular GNM? It does not seem obvious to me. Consider that churches are against people masturbating or having homosexual sex but do not want either masturbation or homosexual sex to be illegal. If the word 'marriage' is an issue, we can revise to civil unions.

Comment: @BCLC - I'm not sure how changing from 'marriage' to 'civil unions' would change anything in DJClayworth's answer. Are you looking for an answer to your question, or ways to circumvent any answers offered? Also, your analogy about churches not wanting sexually deviant acts to be illegal sounds sketchy to me. I mean, there were sodomy laws in some US states until 2003. Can you provide a statement from the churches that you're thinking of that explicitly states that they don't want homosexual sex to be illegal?

Answer (score 0):

The Christian Church cannot support homosexuality based on numerous scriptures, perhaps the most common and direct coming from Romans chapter 1.  On the other hand, Christians cannot expect the world to live by God’s rules if they do not recognize God.  That is literally between them and God.
More to your point, the concept of gender neutral marriage requires the “re-definition” of marriage.  In other words, taking a word that has a specific meaning and changing that meaning.  If I were to take the word mortgage and re-define it to suit my purpose, I can assure you the bank would be quick to protest and, rightfully so.  Words have meaning; and if we arbitrarily assign new or revised meanings to words, then truth no longer exists because we can shape it as we see fit if enough people agree.  This particular word is Christian or, at least, religious in nature and has become secularized over time.  The significance of the now mandated acceptance of GNM is that Christians with sincerely held beliefs about the morality of homosexuality and homosexual marriage will be forced to choose whether to hold true to their beliefs or face the penalty of law.  Under these circumstances, who now is being persecuted?

Answer (score 0):

God has a plan for His children which involves helping us live happy lives and developing God-like attributes. The plan started with Adam and Eve in the Garden of Eden:

> Genesis 1:27-28
>   27 So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.
>   28 And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth,

The commandment given to Adam and Eve  to multiply and replenish the Earth applies to us today as well. A couple that does not consist of a man and a woman cannot fulfill this commandment.

> Genesis 2:24
>   Therefore shall a man leave his father and his mother, and shall cleave unto his wife: and they shall be one flesh.

Here God gives us a commandment which goes along with the one about multiplying and replenishing the earth. Why would God give us these commandments if they weren't for our own well being?

Marriage between a man and a woman constitute the basic building blocks of society. It is in this framework that children are most likely to get the love and care that they need to be healthy individuals.

A healthy society is made up of healthy families.

One of the concepts in ethics is universalizability. Which is to ask what if everyone did it?  If we all turned to homosexuality, you can see that in a hundred years, the earth would be de-populated.  Thus, God's purposes would be thwarted.

Family is important to God. Look at the promises made to Abraham in Genesis 22:

> 17 That in blessing I will bless thee, and in multiplying I will multiply thy seed as the stars of the heaven, and as the sand which is upon the sea shore; and thy seed shall possess the gate of his enemies;
>   18 And in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed; because thou hast obeyed my voice.

Our culture values living for yourself without regard for what is good for society. With no fault divorce, if either partner in the marriage decides its too inconvenient to stay married, then a divorce is granted. This concept of marriage for convenience extends to incorporate the concept of same sex marriage. In both cases, the idea is to grant as much liberty to adults without regard to how it affects society at large, or children specifically.

The God of Christianity is a God of sacrifice. He sent his only begotten son to redeem his children. Just as Abraham was commanded to sacrifice Isaac, God wants us to give him a broken heart and contrite spirit. How can we learn to do that when our natural tendency is to live for ourselves?  By entering into marriage and having children, we learn to sacrifice and gain a perspective on life that is tough to gain in any other way.

Comment: Welcome Brian!  Thanks for contributing.  This answer is okay, but it doesn't seem to directly deal with the question of "why not gender-neutral secular marriage"?  The "universalizability" argument as stated makes no sense to me, since by that you could argue that being a programmer is unethical, because if everyone was a programmer, everyone would starve.  Please take a minute to learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and review [how to write a good, supported answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).